# Reuse texture SDL

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm making my first SDL2 game, I have a *texture* where I draw my game but after each rendering the texture is blanked, I need to have my original texture unmodified.

I have easily made this with *surface* but it was too slow.

I draw random artefacts on this texture that disappears with the time, I use `SDL_RenderFill` to shade the texture.

Anyone know how to do this ?

EDIT: Here's the code of the texture rendering

```
int gv_render(void) // This is called every 10ms
{
gv_lock;
int nexttimeout;
// Clear the screen
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer,NULL);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
// Render view specific stuff
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer,gv_screen); // gv_screen is my screen texture
switch (player_view) { // I have multiple views
case pvsound:nexttimeout=wave_render();break; // <- THE 2ND FUNCTION \/
};
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
// Final screen rendering
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer,NULL);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,gv_screen,NULL,NULL);
gv_unlock;
return nexttimeout;
};
int wave_render(void) // I (will) have multiple view modes
{
  game_wave *currwave = firstwave; // First wave is the first element of a linked list
  game_wave *prevwave = firstwave;  
  map_block* block;
  map_block* oldblock;
  gv_lock;
  // Load the old texture
  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,gv_screen,NULL,NULL);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
  // Dark the screen
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,8);
  SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer,NULL);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
  // Now I travel my list
  while (currwave) {
    // Apply block info
    /* skipped non graphics */
    // Draw the wave point
    uint8_t light; // Wave have a strong that decrease with time
    if (currwave->strong>=1.0)
      light = 255; // Over 1 it don't decrease
    else light = currwave->strong*255; // Now they aren't fully white
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,light,light,light,255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, currwave->xpos,currwave->ypos);
    // Switch to next wave
    prevwave = currwave; // There also code is the skipped part
    currwave = currwave->next;
  };
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  gv_unlock;
  return 10;
};
```

```

Comment: Why do you need your original texture to be unmodified?

Comment: I'm making a game where you have a black screen and when you walk you see sound waves that reflects on walls and blabla. My implementation draw lines on a texture that's regularly darken to vanish old waves.

Comment: Hard to understand with so vague description and without the code. You probably should add a code where you update texture, as well as code where you want yo use its contents that (presumably) isn't there.

Comment: SDL simply takes what you blit and renders it to the screen. It has no facility to remember what it just drew. Your goal would be to only have to re-draw the small portion of the screen that has changed, similar to frame-deferencing in video. There are many approaches that can be tried -- but the comparative discussion is way overbroad from a SO question and more appropriate for the [GameDev StackExchage Site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do but if you only need blending then it is ok to do so. With blending enabled, your updates will blend with render target's previous contents. Your RenderCopy from texture to itself makes no sense though.

Comment: @keltar The problem is that (SDL_RenderPresent)[https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent] `invalidate the backbuffer`, the previous content is lost with texture (surfaces doesn't have this problem).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin okay, I will try to find a other way to get what I want.

Comment: @MiniApp but your target texture isn't a backbuffer. And unless I'm complelety out of touch here, you really don't need RenderPresent to complete rendering to texture - only to swap screen buffers.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be complicated, as say  @david C. Rankin the SDL renderer is faster than surface but more or less *write-only* ([SDL_RenderReadPixels](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels) and [SDL_UpdateTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture) could do the job in non realtime case).

I have changed my method, I use a linked list of pixels coordinates with entry points in a 256 items array.

My source code is now :

```
struct game_wave_point {
  struct game_wave_point *next;
  int x;
  int y;  
};typedef struct game_wave_point game_wave_point;

game_wave_point* graph_waves[256] = {NULL,NULL,...};

wave_render(void)
{
  game_wave *currwave = firstwave;
  // Perform the darkening
  int i;
  uint8_t light;
  for (i=1;i<=255;i++)
    graph_waves[i-1] = graph_waves[i];
  graph_waves[255] = NULL;
  // Remove unvisible point
  game_wave_point* newpoint;
  while (graph_waves[0]) {
    newpoint = graph_waves[0];
    graph_waves[0] = newpoint->next;
    free(newpoint);
  };    
  // Wave heartbeat...
  while (currwave) {
    /* blablabla */
    // Add the drawing point
    newpoint = malloc(sizeof(game_wave_point));
    newpoint->next = graph_waves[light];
    newpoint->x = currwave->xpos*pixelsperblock;
    newpoint->y = currwave->ypos*pixelsperblock;
    if ((newpoint->x<0)|(newpoint->y<0))
       free(newpoint);
    else graph_waves[light] = newpoint;
    /* blablabla */
  };
  // Now perform the drawing
  for (i=1;i<=255;i++) {
    newpoint = graph_waves[i];
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,i,i,i,255);
    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer,&light,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    while (newpoint) {
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer,newpoint->x,newpoint->y);
      newpoint = newpoint->next;
    };
  };
  return 10;
};
```

This work well on my computer (progressive slow appear in a case that I will never reach).
Next optimization maybe performed with Linux [mremap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) and similar, this will allow creating a simple array that work with [SDL_RenderDrawPoints](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) without slowness of realloc() on big array.